# iOS: Create shortcut to send current website from Safari to Firefox

Tags: ios, safari, firefox, shortcuts-app

On Mac, I mainly use a Firefox/Gecko-based browser, while on iOS I mainly use Safari (since Apple unfortunately still does not allow non-Webkit-based browsers).

So I often find myself in a situation where I want to open a website, which I opened on my iPhone on my Mac. I thought a simple solution would be to write a shortcut that sends the current website from Safari to iOS-Firefox which then syncs via Firefox sync to my Mac. However, I seem to be incapable of defining such a shortcut (admittedly, I never really got much into shortcuts so I also am a novice at best).

My idea was to use a URL scheme to open the URL in Firefox such as `firefox://open-url?url=[TheCurrentURL]`, however, I have no idea how to even tell my iPhone to do this via the Shortcuts menu?!

This is my current (not working) trial to set up a corresponding shortcut:

[image]

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: unfortunately not. At some point I just gave up honestly

Answer (score 1):

The error obviously comes from the "Expand" part of the shortcut, just remove it. The following works:

[image]

Comment: If I do this and use it, then my phone complains about `The URL "firefox://" is missing a hostname` in the "Open" field

Comment: @uzer.name I get the same error as you when I try to run the shortcut when the Firefox app is not installed on my iPhone. Have you checked you have Firefox installed properly on your iPhone?

Comment: I am currently posting from there. I guess I have it properly installed ;)

Comment: @uzer.name Well, I don't know what to say. Perhaps you have Firefox Focus installed instead of the normal Firefox app? Maybe try uninstalling and re-installing it? :)